# HttpInterceptor doesn’t work with lazy loaded modules

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I have implemented the lazy-loaded module in my app and yesterday I added HTTPIntercepter and routing stopped working.

I have tried to follow every possible solution but when app load first time it gives an error message

```
vendor.js:75314 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module './login/login.module'
Error: Cannot find module './login/login.module'
```

I have followed this page also but it does not help to solve my issue
https://dev.to/devakone/angular-when-httpinterceptor-doesn-t-work-with-lazy-loaded-modules-3ipg

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { AdminLayoutComponent } from "./templates/admin-layout/admin-layout.component";
import { AuthLayoutComponent } from "./templates/auth-layout/auth-layout.component";


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "admin",
        loadChildren:
          "./view/administrator/administrator.module#adminstratorModule"
      },
      {
        path: "superadmin",
        loadChildren: "./view/superadmin/superadmin.module#superadminModule"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: "",
    component: AuthLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: "login", loadChildren: "./login/login.module#LoginModule" }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: "enabled" })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/header/header.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { SuperadminDashboardComponent } from './view/dashboards/superadmin-dashboard/superadmin-dashboard.component';
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from './view/dashboards/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component';
import { ProviderDashboardComponent } from './view/dashboards/provider-dashboard/provider-dashboard.component';
import { ClientDashboardComponent } from './view/dashboards/client-dashboard/client-dashboard.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './shared/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { VaccineInventoryListComponent } from './view/immunizations/vaccine-inventory/vaccine-inventory-list/vaccine-inventory-list.component';
import { ImmunizationAlertsListComponent } from './view/immunizations/immunization-alerts/immunization-alerts-list/immunization-alerts-list.component';
import { ImmunizationRecordsListComponent } from './view/immunizations/immunization-records/immunization-records-list/immunization-records-list.component';
import { ProviderRolesComponent } from './view/provider/provider-roles/provider-roles.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BroadcasterService } from 'ng-broadcaster';
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastModule, ToastOptions } from 'ng6-toastr';
import { CustomToastrOption } from './shared/shared-component/custom-toastr-option';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ChildrenSettingsComponent } from './view/children/children-settings/children-settings.component';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared/shared.module';
import { NgDatepickerModule } from 'ng2-datepicker';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './view/user-profile/user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { UserProfileContactComponent } from './view/user-profile/user-profile-contact/user-profile-contact.component';
import { UserProfileGuardianComponent } from './view/user-profile/user-profile-guardian/user-profile-guardian.component';
import { UserProfileChildrenComponent } from './view/user-profile/user-profile-children/user-profile-children.component';
import { UserProfileSiblingsComponent } from './view/user-profile/user-profile-siblings/user-profile-siblings.component';
import { UserProfileChildrenCountComponent } from './view/user-profile/user-profile-children-count/user-profile-children-count.component';
import { UserProfileAppointmentsComponent } from './view/user-profile/user-profile-appointments/user-profile-appointments.component';
import { UserProfileVaccinesDueComponent } from './view/user-profile/user-profile-vaccines-due/user-profile-vaccines-due.component';
import { UserProfileClientCountComponent } from './view/user-profile/user-profile-client-count/user-profile-client-count.component';
import { UserProfileVaccinesAdministeredComponent } from './view/user-profile/user-profile-vaccines-administered/user-profile-vaccines-administered.component';
import { ChangepasswordComponent } from './view/changepassword/changepassword.component';
import { AngularDateTimePickerModule } from 'angular2-datetimepicker';
import { AngularGooglePlaceModule } from 'angular-google-place';
import { AuthLayoutComponent } from './templates/auth-layout/auth-layout.component';
import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './templates/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
import { AdminProfileComponent } from './view/profile-page/admin-profile/admin-profile.component';
import { ClientProfileComponent } from './view/profile-page/client-profile/client-profile.component';
import { ProviderProfileComponent } from './view/profile-page/provider-profile/provider-profile.component';
import { SuperadminProfileComponent } from './view/profile-page/superadmin-profile/superadmin-profile.component';
import { childrenModule } from './view/children/children.module';
import { EncounterListComponent } from './view/children/encounter/encounter-list/encounter-list.component';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { VaccineSeriesComponent } from './view/immunizations/vaccine-series/vaccine-series.component';
import { InterceptService } from './shared/intercept.service';
import { LoginModule } from './login/login.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [

    HeaderComponent,
    SuperadminDashboardComponent,
    AdminDashboardComponent,
    ProviderDashboardComponent,
    ClientDashboardComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    VaccineInventoryListComponent,
    ImmunizationAlertsListComponent,
    ImmunizationRecordsListComponent,
    ProviderRolesComponent,
    ChildrenSettingsComponent,
    UserProfileComponent,
    UserProfileContactComponent,
    UserProfileGuardianComponent,
    UserProfileChildrenComponent,
    UserProfileSiblingsComponent,
    UserProfileChildrenCountComponent,
    UserProfileAppointmentsComponent,
    UserProfileVaccinesDueComponent,
    UserProfileClientCountComponent,
    UserProfileVaccinesAdministeredComponent,
    ChangepasswordComponent,
    AuthLayoutComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent,
    AdminProfileComponent,
    ClientProfileComponent,
    ProviderProfileComponent,
    SuperadminProfileComponent,
    EncounterListComponent,
    VaccineSeriesComponent,
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: '[API Key redacted]'
    }),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    OwlDateTimeModule,
    OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
    CommonModule,
    ToastModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    NgDatepickerModule,
    SharedModule,
    AngularDateTimePickerModule,
    AngularGooglePlaceModule,
    childrenModule,
    LoginModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [BroadcasterService, {
    provide: ToastOptions, useClass: CustomToastrOption},
    {provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS ,useClass: InterceptService,multi:true},
    ,DatePipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Hi Shah. My english is very poor, but the first once advice , are you using google maps, you have to **remove** apikey or put **fake key**, it´s possible that key it´s not trust. in the other question. if i don`t remember bad, you use lazayload(old mode), angular 8 has new way to use, and better performance  lazayload(ivy),  if you  use lazay load you hate put the interceptors in every module.

Comment: I am using angular 7, you mean if I want to use HTTP interceptor I need to put that in every module?

Comment: Hi Shah. you have to interceptors in every modules that you use, you try put the service in app.modules, together interceptor, but  i dont know if it  works, you declare interceptors in modules that you use, sorry my english.

Comment: Did you solve this?